# Mysql get three sets of rows depending on field

Tags: php, mysql

I want three sets of rows in my query, with 100 in each. Each set with a different data value. So like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM actions WHERE appid='$appid' AND email!='' AND user_name!='' AND data='24' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 100") or die(mysql_error());
$result .= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM actions WHERE appid='$appid' AND email!='' AND user_name!='' AND data='23' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 100") or die(mysql_error());
$result .= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM actions WHERE appid='$appid' AND email!='' AND user_name!='' AND data='22' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 100") or die(mysql_error());
```

How can I get the result in one query?

Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM actions WHERE appid='$appid' AND email!='' AND user_name!='' AND data in('24','23','22') ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 100"` or try `union`.

Comment: Hmm, that won't limit to 100 in **each** group of `data`.

Comment: more tips: `!=` is a MySQL-specific operator. Use the identical `<>` instead for portability; you do not need to quote numbers either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA UNION SELECT * FROM tableB UNION SELECT * FROM tableC
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I limit 100 in each SELECT? I get an error when I input LIMIT 100 after each SELECT. But when I throw at the end of the query, it works fine.

Comment: @CasperSlynge wrap each query part in parentheses: `(SELECT ... LIMIT 100) UNION (SELECT...`

Answer (score 2):

Use `union`

```
    $final_query=$query1." union ".$query2." union ".$query3;

    and 
    mysql_query($final_query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Union Like

```
SELECT * FROM tableA UNION SELECT * FROM tableB UNION SELECT * FROM tableC
```

If you want to allow duplicate as well then try `UNION ALL` like

```
SELECT * FROM tableA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tableB UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tableC
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to do this work

```
(SELECT * FROM actions WHERE appid='$appid' AND email!='' AND user_name!='' AND data='24' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 100) 
UNION
(SELECT * FROM actions WHERE appid='$appid' AND email!='' AND user_name!='' AND data='23' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 100)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM actions WHERE appid='$appid' AND email!='' AND user_name!='' AND data='22' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 100)
```

Comment: This is what I want, but it gives me an error, as there is an ORDER BY and LIMIT 100 before each UNION.

Comment: check it again please i edited my answer i think its ok if isn't give me the error

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `UNION`.

```
$result = mysql_query("
  (SELECT * FROM actions WHERE appid='$appid' AND email!='' AND user_name!='' AND data='24' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 100)
  UNION
  (SELECT * FROM actions WHERE appid='$appid' AND email!='' AND user_name!='' AND data='23' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 100)
  UNION
  (SELECT * FROM actions WHERE appid='$appid' AND email!='' AND user_name!='' AND data='22' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 100)
");
```

More options [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/).